# sql query, order by value when field matches

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have data as follows:

```
data_id   name            value
-----------------------------------------
1        Address123       my street
1        Order-Date        12/23/2018 
1        firstName        Joe    
2        Address          345 other street
2        Order-Date        12/31/2018
2        firstName        Peter
```

...and so on..

How can I write a query to return the data ordered by 'OrderDate' using ID as the Group

e.g.

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_cf7_data_entry 
WHERE cf7_id = 7 
AND data_id IN (SELECT * 
                FROM (
                  SELECT data_id 
                  FROM wp_cf7_data_entry 
                  WHERE 1 = 1 
                   AND cf7_id = 7 
                  GROUP BY data_id 
                  ORDER BY case 
                               when name = 'order-date' THEN 'value' 
                           end DESC,'data_id')
```

basically I want to use the subquery as the order by so results are sorted by Order-Date.

Comment: Excuse me.  `select *` with `group by`?  That doesn't make sense.

Comment: What are your expected results?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Single quotes are for string literals, i.e. `'name_field' = 'OrderDate'` will always be false.

Comment: here is the actual query from wordpress ( i have modified to try and order by date)

    SELECT * FROM `wp_cf7_data_entry` WHERE `cf7_id` = 7 AND data_id IN(SELECT * FROM (SELECT data_id FROM `wp_cf7_data_entry` WHERE 1 = 1 AND `cf7_id` = 7 GROUP BY `data_id` ORDER BY case when `name` = 'order-date' THEN 'value' end DESC,'data_id') temp_table)

Comment: I need this query to return the results order_date order ..

Comment: An order by in a sub-query for an IN condition is useless

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to use `conditional aggregation`:

```
select id, 
       max(case when name_field = 'OrderDate' then value end) as OrderDate,
       max(case when name_field = 'Address' then value end) as Address,
       max(case when name_field = 'Name' then value end) as Name
from yourtable
group by id
order by max(case when name_field = 'OrderDate' then value end)
```

This creates a single row for each `id` and orders the results by the order date value.

Comment: here is the actual query from wordpress SELECT * FROM wp_cf7_data_entry WHERE cf7_id = 7 AND data_id IN(SELECT * FROM (SELECT data_id FROM wp_cf7_data_entry WHERE 1 = 1 AND cf7_id = 7 GROUP BY data_id ORDER BY case when name = 'order-date' THEN 'value' end DESC,'data_id') temp_table)

Comment: @CraigJohnstone That query doesn't make any sense - why would you `order by` something in your subquery?  I'm surprised that even runs... Either way, edit your question with the expected results from your sample data...

Answer (score 0):

You dont need a group by as I can see for each id theres only one namefield as ordereddate

```
    SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE NAME_FIELD = 
   'OrderedDate' order by NAME_FIELD
```